# How to keep scroll-bar hidden and show it when max-height is over?

Tags: html, css

I have a structure like this:

```css
pre {
 word-warp: normal;
 display: block;
 padding: 5px 8px;
 width: auto;
 background-color: #eee;
 margin-bottom: 1em;
 max-height: 300px;
 line-height: 1.8;
 direction: ltr;
 overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<pre>
<code>
In this case both X and Y scroll-bar(s) has to be hidden
</code>
</pre>

<hr>

<pre>
<code>
In this case just Y-scroll-bar has to appears
<br>
In this case just Y-scroll-bar has to appears
<br>
In this case just Y-scroll-bar has to appears
<br>
In this case just Y-scroll-bar has to appears
<br>
</code>
</pre>

<hr>

<pre>
<code>
In this case just X-scroll-bar has to apears -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
</code>
</pre>
```

Actually I'm trying to create something exactly like stackoverflow-code-method-UI. How can I do that?

Comment: I guess you want to change the `overflow: scroll;` to `overflow: auto`?

Comment: @NicoO WTF ...! Just that!!! Thank you buddy. You solved my problem by a small comment `;-)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to set a max-width for the x scrollbar, but then changeing overflow:scroll to overflow:auto works exactly how you want.

```css
pre {
    word-warp: normal;
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 8px;
    width: auto;
    background-color: #eee;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    max-height: 300px;
    max-width:300px;
    line-height: 1.8;
    direction: ltr;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<pre>
<code>
In this case both X and Y scroll-bar(s) has to be hidden
</code>
</pre>

<hr>

<pre>
<code>
In this case just Y-scroll-bar has to appears
<br>
In this case just Y-scroll-bar has to appears
<br>
In this case just Y-scroll-bar has to appears
<br>
In this case just Y-scroll-bar has to appears
<br>
</code>
</pre>

<hr>

<pre>
<code>
In this case just X-scroll-bar has to apears -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
</code>
</pre>
```